# Problems with the create policy in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, policy, user-roles, laravel-authorization

I'm implementing roles and permission for a project, and using policies, but I have a problem when I want to authorize or not the creation of new records in the patients table, very simple stuff.
I have this in my PatientPolicy

```
// Only the users with root or admin roles can create patients;
public function create(User $user){
    return ($user->hasRole('root') || $user->hasRole('admin'));
}

// only the patient creator can edit the patient and see the edit button
public function update(User $user, Patient $patient){
    return $user->id == $patient->user_id;
}
```

AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    'App\Patient' => 'App\Policies\PatientPolicy'
];
```

PatientController

```
public function edit(Patient $patient){
    if(Gate::denies('update', $patient)){
        abort(403, 'No esta autorizado de estar aqui');
    }
    return view('patients.edit', compact('patient'));
}

public function create(){
    if(Gate::denies('create')){
        abort(403, 'Usted no esta autorizado para crear pacientes');
    }
    return view('patients.create');
}
```

and in my views

```
@can('create')
    <li class="header">PROCESOS</li>
    <li><a href="/paciente/create"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Apertura de Historia Clínica</span></a></li>
@endcan
```

The problem is that the create policy is always returning false even for those users that are suppossed to be allowed to perform the action, however the edit policy works perfectly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a policy method with no argument in Laravel 5.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37242321/how-to-define-a-policy-method-with-no-argument-in-laravel-5-2)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `Gate::denies` and `@can` methods don't know which model and policy class they should look for when there is no argument to correspond, so use this code instead:

```
public function create(){
    if(Gate::denies('create', Patient::class)) {
        abort(403, 'Usted no esta autorizado para crear pacientes');
    }
    return view('patients.create');
}
```

and in your views:

```
@can('create', App\Patient::class)
    <li class="header">PROCESOS</li>
    <li><a href="/paciente/create"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span>Apertura de Historia Clínica</span></a></li>
@endcan
```

You can check my full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37261276/3477084